# Unable to filter the data on multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, angular

HI I have JSON Array from DB as below structure

```
[{
Attachments: null
ConstructionTypeID: "c2da0a32-2a07-11e9-9500-90b11c61d394"
ConstructionTypeName: "New"
ContractTypeID: "f7adf340-2a07-11e9-9500-90b11c61d394"
ContractTypeName: "Private"
Description: "ddd"
EndDate: "2019-06-27T18:30:00.000Z"
IssueCount: 0
ModelCount: 1
Name: "Sang"
ProjectAddress: null
ProjectID: "01418e66-85f3-11e9-a8cd-38607725a846"
ProjectSubTypeID: "dccd7be7-2a06-11e9-9500-90b11c61d394"
ProjectSubTypeName: "Retail"
ProjectTypeID: "c7569d2a-2a05-11e9-9500-90b11c61d394"
ProjectTypeName: "Commercial"
RevisionID: "1"
RuleCount: 0
StartDate: "2019-06-02T18:30:00.000Z"
SubProjCount: 0
}]
```

and i have multiple filters to apply as per user requirement.Please see the below screenshot provided.
[image]

**Here user can change filter text box and date Range. so based on these two conditions i have to filter the records and show them in the view. if user clear/update the filter text/ date range values , then corresponding fuctionality should work. if user remove two conditions i have to show all the records again. Please provide if you have any idea. thanks in advance.**
i implemented below but not working.

```
filterProjectDatas() {
    this.filteredData = [];
    if ('Name' in this.data[0]) {
      this.filteredData = this.data.filter((item: any) => {
        return ((this.filterModal.searchStirng && item.Name.toLowerCase().includes(this.filterModal.searchStirng.toLowerCase())) &&
          (this.filterModal.dateFilter && (new Date(item.StartDate) > this.filterModal.dateFilter[0] && new Date(item.EndDate) < this.filterModal.dateFilter[1])));
      });
    }
    // if ('IssueName' in this.data[0]) {
    // }
    this.filterData.emit(this.filteredData);
  }
```

Comment: Try chaining multiple filter() operators, each with its own condition. Then you can check if any of your filter conditions are erroneous by tap() -ing between each of them.

Comment: you mean multiple methods or anything else, provide any example you have

Comment: What will be the value of `this.filterModal.dateFilter` if Date Range isn't selected? Will it be null or undefined?

Comment: value will be undefined only

Comment: Since they are &&'d together, they could simply cascade. Output of one filter becomes input to the next. As it appears other filters are on the way (id range, status). That allows for conditional processing of filters.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `||` operator for each filter's group. This will check the second condition only if the `searchStirng` and `dateFilter` have [`non-falsy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value:

```
this.filteredData = this.data.filter((item) =>
  (!this.filterModal.searchStirng || item.Name.toLowerCase().includes(this.filterModal.searchStirng.toLowerCase()))
  && (!this.filterModal.dateFilter || (new Date(item.StartDate) > this.filterModal.dateFilter[0] && new Date(item.EndDate) < this.filterModal.dateFilter[1]))
)
```

If `searchStirng` is empty or null, `!searchStirng` will return `true` and the second condition in that group will not be checked.